# $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{\operatorname{arccot}(x) - \frac{\pi}{2}}{x}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{\operatorname{arccot}(x) - \frac{\pi}{2}}{x}$$

The title says everything. I already know the limit is $+\infty$, I just want to see how it can be calculated. (Please don't use L'Hôpital's rule, I haven't covered it yet at school)

Comment: Are you familiar to Taylor expansion?

Comment: Please, avoid double dollar signs in titles and include your question in the body of the post, not only in the title.

Comment: Never heard about it, sadly

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Okay, sorry about that.

Comment: The expression is by definition the (leftsided) derivative of $\arccot(x)$ at $x=0$. By the ways, this makes the result $-1$, not $+\infty$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The limit of arccot$(x)$ when $x\to0$, $x\lt0$, is $-\pi/2$, not $+\pi/2$, hence there is no derivative here and the result is not $-1$.

Comment: Did doesn't miss anything. Ever.

Comment: @Did: What can we do when we find the plot of the function admits Hagens point? Thanks

Comment: @BabakS. look at my answer, Did is totally right

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Let me qualify my last statement: there is apparently some variations in the [definition of arccot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot+x). My comment is based on W|A definition and yours on [WP's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions). The rest is theology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first a plot to show the limit is not -1.

[image]

The limit of $\operatorname{arccot}(x)$ as $x\to 0$ and $x<0$ is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

To see that, we use that $\operatorname{arccot(x)}=\frac{1}{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$
and hence
$$\underset{x<0}{\lim_{x\to 0}} \operatorname{arccot}(x)=\lim_{x\to -\infty} \arctan(x)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

So your limit is the same as 
$$-\underset{x<0}{\lim_{x\to 0}}\frac{\pi}{x}$$
This is the same as 
$$\pi \cdot \underset{x>0}{\lim_{x\to 0}} \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Thanks, very good explanation, I actually understood it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $\mathrm arccot x = \pi/2 - \arctan x$. Try to recover the definition of derivative for the arccot (or better: the $\arctan$) function:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\mathrm {arccot}x - \pi/2}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{-\arctan x}{x}
= - \arctan'(0) = -1.
$$

Comment: the derivatives of arccot and arctan are bounded and hence won't get near infty anywhere

Comment: We don't agree on the definition of arccot (quite a not useful function). I took the definition given in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: There seems to be some variations in the [definition of arccot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot+x).